# Using a shifted bell curve to create random.choices weights

Tags: python, random, statistics, probability

I'm a beginner to Python, attempting something a bit too complicated for me.

I want to output a list (*q*), *k*-items long, where each item is one of five options (contained in list *w*).

```
w = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

I'm using random.choices to create list *q*.

I want each item's weighting to be governed by a skewed bell curve (or even a rough approximation of one), where the horizontal position of the curve's peak equals *p*. *p* can range from 0.1 to 1.

So, if *p* = 0.55, item *c* should have the highest probability of appearing in list *q*, with *b* and *d* having the second highest probability, and *a* and *e* having the lowest probability. If *p* = 0.1, *a* should be the most likely to appear and *e* the least likely, and so on.

I've found scipy.stats.skewnorm, which seems like it could work. However, I'm really struggling to adapt it into the form I need.

I'm after a function where 0 ≤ y ≤ 1 and 0 ≤ x ≤ 1.2. I then want this function to create the five weights for random.choices, something like so:

```
p = 0.7

prob_a = f(0.2, p)

prob_b = f(0.4, p)

prob_c = f(0.6, p)

etc...

q = random.choices(w, weights=[prob_a, prob_b, prob_c, etc...], k=10)
```

I'd be extremely grateful for any and all advice, direction, or suggestions! I'm not wedded to either random.choices or skewnorm – if there's a simpler way to achieve a similar result, that'd be amazing!

Comment: why are you using a "skewed bell curve" here?  what are `x` and `y`?

Comment: @SamMason I'm just using `x` and `y` to show the domain and range of the function that I'm after. In my code, `x` will be one of five points (0.2, 0.4, etc...) that I find the function's output for. And `y`: I always want the output to be less than 1.

As for the skewed bell curve: I think I want `y` to fit on the curve of a normal distribution, but with that distribution skewed away from the centre according to `p`. In the end, if `p` = ~0.5, I want list `q` to contain _c_ most of the time, but to sometimes to feature _b_ and _d_, and occasionally to feature _a_ and _e_.

Comment: pretty sure you don't want a skewed distribution then, you just want to move the mean around.  and your relabelling of points just seems to be confusing the issue, using indices is just as powerful and means you don't need to specify them everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've written so far, I think you want to do something like:

```
from scipy import stats
from random import choices

def weighted_choices(w, mu, sd, *, k=1):
    weights = stats.norm(mu, sd).pdf(range(len(w)))
    return choices(w, weights=weights, k=k)
```

where `mu` is the index of `w` you want to be the most likely, and `sd` is how tight you want that selection to be.  e.g.:

- `weighted_choices('abcde', 1, 0.1)` will almost always choose `b`
- `weighted_choices('abcde', 3, 0.5)` will tend to choose `d` but has reasonable chance of choosing `c` or `e`, and much smaller chance of picking `a`
- `weighted_choices('abcde', 2, 10)` is basically uniform